# Checking the return of Multiple mutations requests using Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm making a simple shopping cart using Apollo Client and React, but the total price I'm showing thats retrieved from the server its not making reference to the last request sent but to the last request received. Its there a way to make the requests synchronous or something like that? Or even how to know whats the return from the last mutation sent?

My code:

```
  this.props.mutate({ variables: { input: {
    lineItems: this.productCart
  }}})
  .then(({ data }) => {
    this.setState({
      subtotalPrice : data.manageCheckout.checkout.subtotalPrice
    })
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.warn('there was an error sending the query', error)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% I am following you, but I don't think this isn't support. The mutation query does not wait for the promise to complete.

There is an issue against the [apollo-client](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/1618)

One way you could go about trying to solve this is to use `setTimeout` so youor price is only updated once the store has been updated.

```
 this.props.mutate({ variables: { input: {
    lineItems: this.productCart
  }}})
  .then(({ data }) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ 
      subtotalPrice : data.manageCheckout.checkout.subtotalPrice
    })
   )}
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.warn('there was an error sending the query', error)
  })
```

It's a hack, but it works for me. Still waiting on the github issue for more information.

Comment: That didnt worked :/ Needed to add a loading on the screen for each click to  get everything sync... But thanks for the answer :)